# symfony2 - createQueryBuilder Doctrine build query with first capital letter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I' following a symfony2 tutorial and I've problems with one step.

Tutorial link: http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/12/symfony2-jobeet-day-6-more-with-the-model/

I'm in 'Refactoring' step. I've one this 3 steps:

1- I've correctly modified /src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Job.orm.yml file specifiying the repository

2- I've run the command: php app/console doctrine:generate:entities IbwJobeetBundle

3- And I've added the specified tutorial function por JobRepository.php

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('j')
                ->where('j.expires_at > :date')
                ->setParameter('date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()))
                ->orderBy('j.expires_at', 'DESC');
```

BUT when I refresh my code I get this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT j0_.id AS id0, j0_.type
>   AS type1, j0_.company AS company2, j0_.logo AS logo3, j0_.url AS url4,
>   j0_.position AS position5, j0_.location AS location6, j0_.description
>   AS description7, j0_.how_to_apply AS how_to_apply8, j0_.token AS
>   token9, j0_.is_public AS is_public10, j0_.is_activated AS
>   is_activated11, j0_.email AS email12, j0_.expires_at AS expires_at13,
>   j0_.created_at AS created_at14, j0_.updated_at AS updated_at15,
>   j0_.category_id AS category_id16 FROM Job j0_ WHERE j0_.expires_at > ?
>   ORDER BY j0_.expires_at DESC' with params ["2016-03-17 15:47:19"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'jobeet.Job'
>   doesn't exist

In the symfony profiler I can see the full query:

> SELECT j0_.id AS id0, j0_.type AS type1, j0_.company AS company2,
>   j0_.logo AS logo3, j0_.url AS url4, j0_.position AS position5,
>   j0_.location AS location6, j0_.description AS description7,
>   j0_.how_to_apply AS how_to_apply8, j0_.token AS token9, j0_.is_public
>   AS is_public10, j0_.is_activated AS is_activated11, j0_.email AS
>   email12, j0_.expires_at AS expires_at13, j0_.created_at AS
>   created_at14, j0_.updated_at AS updated_at15, j0_.category_id AS
>   category_id16 FROM Job j0_ WHERE j0_.expires_at > '2016-03-17
>   15:47:19' ORDER BY j0_.expires_at DESC

the table name it's in uppercase! 'Job', not 'job'

Any can help me, please?

Comment: @hasumedic It works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by modifying the entity definition in `Job.orm.yml` by adding the `table` attribute:

```
IbwJobeetBundleEntityJob:
    type: entity
    table: job
    repositoryClass: IbwJobeetBundleRepositoryJobRepository
```